# como puedo poner un boton que ande en el activity_maps?

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

Resulta que estoy desarrollando una aplicacion que utiliza un mapa. Para realizarlo lo genere desde **android studio** con la opcion ***new-> Google -> Google Maps Activity***.

Esto genera una `activity` con un `fragment` que es donde se ecuentra el mapa. Yo quiero poner **botones en esa `activity`** y que al precionarlos se ejecuten metodos definidos en `MapsActivity.java`. Para poner los botones toque el `xml`, pero el problema esta a la hora del metodo `onClick`, ya que no aparecen las funciones definidas en la clase **(tiene un metodo de prueba que muestra un mensaje nomas)**. Y si defino en el `xml` el metodo que ejecutara cuando haga `onclick` **me detiene la aplicacion**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="uap.geocolportaje.geocoportaje.MapsActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.375"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
    tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="uap.geocolportaje.geocoportaje.MapsActivity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnGuardar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGuardar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnUbicacion"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:text="Guardar Ubicacion"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:onClick="Guardar" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUbicacion"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Mi Posicion"
        android:visibility="visible" />


</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Activity:

```
package uap.geocolportaje.geocoportaje;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    /*TODO

     */

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private Marker marcador;
    double lat = 0.0;
    double lng = 0.0;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, null);

    public void Guardar(){
        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Guardar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        miUbicacion();
    }

    public void agregarMarcador(double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate miUbicacion = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 16);
        if (marcador != null)marcador.remove();

        marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(coordenadas)
                .title("Ubicacion Actual")
                //.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                );
        mMap.animateCamera(miUbicacion);
    }

    private void actualizarUbicacion(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            agregarMarcador(lat, lng);
        }
    }

    private void miUbicacion() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        actualizarUbicacion(location);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,15000,0,locListener);
    }

    LocationListener locListener= new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            actualizarUbicacion(location);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    };

    private void GuardarPunto(){
        Conexion con= new Conexion(this,"BD",null,1);

        SQLiteDatabase db=con.getWritableDatabase();

        //TODO
    }

}
```

Comment: Agrega el código y los layouts como texto por favor.

Comment: pusiste "sdasd" como nombre del metodo en el onClick del boton y no tenes ningun metodo llamado "sdasd"

Comment: ahi lo edite para que ejecute el metodo Guardar pero sigue sin aparecer el metodo en el menu de propiedades de diseño, y si se lo pongo en xml me tira error la aplicacion

Comment: Solucionado borrando las lineas: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, null);

Answer (score 0):

inicializa tu boton en el metodo onCreate:

```
Button bttnGuardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGuardar);

bttnGuardar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
//Aqui declaras todo lo que quieres hacer cuando se haga click en el boton
                   GuardarPunto()
                }
            });
```

y elimina el android:onClick="Guardar" del layout

Answer (score 0):

Si defines  `android:onClick` desde el layout y la llamada al método `Guardar`:

es incorrecto llamar de esta forma al método, y obtendrás un error.

```
public void Guardar(){
   ...
   ...
   ...
}
```

**Debes llamar al método de esta forma, recibiendo una vista como parámetro**:

```
public void Guardar(View v){
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardar.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```